# Htaccess rule, convert dash to slash in url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to convert single (first) dash into slash. I have two urls here:

Actuall url: 
`http://localhost/wordpress/accessories-car-alarm-system`.

Should redirect to 
`http://localhost/wordpress/accessories/car-alarm-system`.

I want to convert this specific url from first one to second one. I am using this code but it doesn't work properly.

Whole htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?accessories/(.+)$ /accessories-$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Tried this too:

```
RewriteRule ^/?accessories/(.+)$ /accessories-$1 [L,NC]
```

Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^accessories-(.+)$ accessories/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Without the `/` at the beginning in .htaccess

Comment: Edited my question, please check.

Comment: You try to redirect ?. Witch url is the real one ?

Comment: Actuall url: `http://localhost/wordpress/accessories-car-alarm-system`. Should redirect to `http://localhost/wordpress/accessories/car-alarm-system`. Now clear?

Comment: Great! working fine. I actually put this line before `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use regex in rewrite RewriteTarget ,try

```
RewriteRule ^/?accessories/(.+)$ /accessories-$1 [L,NC]
```

Reference : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Edited my question, please check.

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is not working? what url are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Actuall url: `http://localhost/wordpress/accessories-car-alarm-system`. Should redirect to `http://localhost/wordpress/accessories/car-alarm-system`. Now clear?

Comment: Croises answer worked for me. anything fault in that code?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with the answer. I had also updated the rule but rollbacked when I saw the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
RewriteRule ^/accessories-(.*)$ /accessories/(.*)$
```

Comment: You can add [NC,L].